# Resizing NSTokenField after populating with tokens

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit, nstokenfield

I am using an NSTokenField as a way for users to enter tags. Everything works fine and it hooks up with CoreData managing the tags both when the user adds or deletes a tag.

I recently added logic so that the NSTokenField would resize vertically as the user adds tags and they break to the next line using Andrew Bowman's [IFVerticallyExpandingTextField](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?IFVerticallyExpandingTextField). Again this all works fine.

The issue is that when I have to initially populate the NSTokenField with tags, I need it to resize. I populate the field by calling:

```
[tagField setObjectValue: anArray];
```

Where anArray is a series of objects that represent a tag or a Token. This in turn calls the NSTokenField delegate method

```
tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:
```

Which returns the string representation for the object passed in the previous array.

I need to resize the NSTokenField after all of the calls to displayStringForRepresentedObject. Does anyone have any ideas of a notification or a way of finding out that it's all done? Even a way of calling the resize in between each call to displayStringForRepresentedObject would probably work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your autoresize works with autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something similar to -setNeedsDisplay: and -displayIfNeeded ... i.e., -setNeedsSizeToFit: and -sizeToFitIfNeeded.

You'll just need a "needsSizeToFit" BOOL flag and the -setNeedsSizeToFit: and -sizeToFitIfNeeded methods.

After you set your tokens, call -setNeedsSizeToFit:YES. It in turn will set the instance's needsSizeToFit flag, then if the flag is YES, it will call [self performSelector:@selector(sizeToFitIfNeeded) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]. Your -sizeToFitIfNeeded method will check if your needsSizeToFit flag is YES, call [self sizeToFit], then set the needsSizeToFit flag to NO.

**Update**

Here's [a complete class (JLNAutoSizingTokenField)](http://media.nozzi.name/sourcecode/JLNAutoSizingTokenField.zip) that does basic autosizing as described above. The only augmentation was to call this in the afore-mentioned delegate method:

```
- (NSString *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)aTokenField 
displayStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    [(JLNAutoSizingTokenField *)aTokenField setNeedsSizeToFit:YES];
    return representedObject;
}
```

Comment: I started to do something similar to this but I ran into the issue of not knowing when all my tokens are set. That's the real issue I'm having. They are not set after I setObjectValue. They are only set after each displayStringForRepresentedObject is called.

Comment: Wouldn't -displayStringForRepresentedObject: be called within the same trip through the runloop as your -setObjectValue: call? If so, then the -sizeToFitIfNeeded would be called in the next trip through the runloop, *after* all the calls to -displayStringForRepresentedObject:.

Comment: Worst case scenario: an unsavory-looking-but-functional call to -setNeedsSizeToFit: with each call to -displayStringForRepresentedObject:.

Comment: setObjectValue is called once and then NSTokenField calls displayString for each object in objectValue. I have to try calling the resize method in the diplayStringForRepresentedObject again because when I tried that before it was messing up the strings themselves. The token field didn't like me calling the resize method while it was doing what it needed to do.

Comment: Really unsavory would be, and I haven't tried this yet, would be to call a method each time displayStringForRepresentedObject is called and figuring out if its about to display the last one. At that point call the resize method with a delay of 0.1 or something. Calling resize from the displayStringForRepresentedObject is weird because it returns a string. So I call the resize before it returns the string and then would ultimately end up with one string that wasn't accounted for.

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting my point about the run loop and -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: ...

Comment: But -textDidEndEditing is never called as the text is not actually edited. I will be able try things you've mentioned here later on today and will be able to actually say for sure whats working and whats not.

Comment: I thought about it again and see what you mean now about utilizing the run loop. I'm going to try that later. Thanks.

Comment: I just got it working as you posted the class. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.